# Symfony form doesn't change value by using FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

Following problem I have: In Symfony (Version 4.4.22) I created a FormType with a date-field and a checkbox. If the checkbox was checked then the field should get the value of "31.12.9999".

If a requesting form has the value 1 for the field `infiniteValidTo`, the value of `validTo` should change from empty to "31.12.9999". (In my case the date field has the value 'null' when the form was submitted.)

So I added an EventListener to the form builder with a pre_submit hook that will add this info before the form is validating.

```php
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder      
      ->add('validTo', DateType::class, [
        'required'           => FALSE,
        'format'             => 'dd.MM.yyyy'
      ])
      ->add('infiniteValidTo', CheckboxType::class, [
        'required'           => FALSE
      ])
      ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        if (isset($data['infiniteValidTo']) && $data['infiniteValidTo'] === '1') {
          $data['validTo'] = '31.12.9999';
        }
        $event->setData($data);
      });
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
      'data_class'  => SettingFormModel::class,
      'constraints' => [
        new Callback([
          'callback' => [$this, 'validateFormModel']
        ])
      ]
    ]);
  }

  /**
   * @param SettingFormModel          $object
   * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
   */
  public function validateFormModel(SettingFormModel $object, ExecutionContextInterface $context): void {
    dump($object);
  }
```

Before leaving the listener method the data-array has the correct values (by dumping the variable).

For validating the form in a dynamical way, I defined a callback method for the data object. When the data container arrives the methods, my change of the validTo field is gone. If I change the field into a simple text field it works, but not for a date field.

After debugging a lot of time, I saw that the method mapFormsToData doesn't transform the change into the form object.

Do I made a mistake by configuration or is this a bug in symfony? Has somebody else the same issue with a form?

Comment: According to documentation, the default format for the `DateType` is `yyyy-mm-dd`, not `dd.mm.yyyy`.

Comment: Please provide some more context and what do you expect to happen? 
Try to rephrase the question and check these guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Meanwhile here are some links that might help.

DateType docs https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/forms/types/date.html.
Unmapped fields  https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/forms.html#unmapped-fields.

Comment: @Reqven: I did changed the settings for the date format. I forgot copy this line.

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake. The setter of SettingFormModel was not correct. After repairing the Listener works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a post_submit event

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder      
      ->add('validTo', DateType::class, [
        'required'           => FALSE
      ])
      ->add('infiniteValidTo', CheckboxType::class, [
        'required'           => FALSE
      ]);

    $builder->get('infiniteValidTo')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        if ($event->getForm()->getData()) {
            $event->getForm->getParent()->getData()->setValidTo(new \DateTime('9999-12-31'));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I added your suggestion, but it didn't have any effect. The value of field ```validTo``` is empty.

Comment: changed `if` condition